# Extract map information from Bing Maps

Tags: bing-maps

I would like to write a navigation software for windows phone 7 that is available without being on the internet. Therefore, I would like to download the map information from Bing maps. Not the entire world or country, just a small city - because this software is just for me and I only need navigation within my home town.

What I basically need is something similar to the map export that OpenStreetMap offers. I could not find anything equivalent on bing maps, so I wrote a program that queries bing maps (through the API) for routes. It then saves intersections and thus builds a graph. This technically works and I get a lot of streets, but sometimes bing leaves out a single intersection. In that case, my data will become invalid.

So I was wondering if there is any way of asking the API directly for a map export, returning something like an array of streets that is within a certain boundary rectangle. (Or something similar)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no standard API call in Bing Maps API that will let you do this.

Downloading all the street data within "a small city" would violate the terms of service. See 8.2(r) at http://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html.

If you want that data, you can try OpenStreetMap or else you would probably have to license the data from a commercial provider of such things which is no doubt very expensive.

Comment: I was not aware that extracting that information violates the terms of service. Thanks for your response! I will go for OpenStreetMaps then.